# Why is there a 'js' command on Node JS for Linux?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I've installed on a XUbuntu 13.10 the software Node.js through package manager:

```
xxx@xxx:/$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

All seems good but along with `nodejs` executable I've found a `js` executable.

Both, if called with `-v` option, show `v0.10.15` and I've successfully used both of them as a Javascript interpreter.

My question is: is there any difference between `nodejs` command and `js` command? Is `js` just an alias for the `nodejs` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with `/etc/alternatives`, the Ubuntu/Debian alternatives mechanism.

- `/usr/bin/js` — is a link to
- `/etc/alternatives/js` — is a link to
- `/usr/bin/node`

Thus if you've got `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, running `js` is effectively exactly the same as running `node` (except that two symlinks have to be traversed, which is not a significant cost). Using `js` in scripts (for example) would allow the system to be configured to use an alternative to the installed Node version — maybe a different version, or a version built with some experimental feature.

You can read more about it in the [`update-alternatives` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).

Comment: Good, forgot about issuing ls -l to find links... -.- too few hours of sleep, I suppose, I'll accept ASAP

Answer (score 0):

`js` command is a generic command that invokes any javascript interpreter installed on the system.

`node` command is a command that invokes node.js.

The difference will be if you install another javascript interpreter on your system, it will be linked as /usr/bin/js, but not be in /usr/bin/node obviously.